# Expected undergraduate semesters and requirements for graduate students

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, mathematics, computer-science

I have been wondering recently about how graduate schools and in general anyone who reviews my academic record views coops. By coop, I mean a semester taken off from undergraduate studies to work in a related industry. If the student takes more than 8 semesters to graduate, is it a problem? Should the student (if they can) extend their studies by an additional semester so that they graduate in the spring, or is a fall graduation equally acceptable. Do grad programs accept students to start in the spring, or only the fall?

I tried to keep the question above general pursuant to the guidelines in the FAQ, however I will appreciate anyone who is willing to review my specific case.

I am a sophomore in CS at a strong US engineering school. I have 2 summer internships, and now a coop under my belt. My problem is, I do not like any of the work I have experienced. I don't mind programming, but it is not something I can do for 40 hours a week without getting really bored. I only really enjoy the difficult math problems, which don't come up that often for most CS jobs,and I absolutely hate wires, soldering, network-admin and low-level computer work.

I want to switch to Math and pursue a graduate degree in either data science or applied math. I can graduate on time by dropping to a math major and a cs and stat double minor, or I can add a semester and get a double major in math and cs or stats, or take graduate classes. I should also mention that my GPA is currently at 3.2 largely because I have tried to alter the CS curriculum to incorporate the things that interest me (a realistic expectation is a 3.4-3.5 graduating GPA). My final consideration is that the math dept at my school is somewhat low on most academic rankings, whereas my CS dept is in the thunder-weight category trailing the likes of MIT. It would not be hard for me to find research opportunities in either department, which I intend to do either way.

Answer (score 7):

> I have been wondering recently about how graduate schools and in general anyone who reviews my academic record views coops.

Coops are fantastic.  Especially for programs in computer science / applied math / data science, *relevant* industry experience is a strong advantage in graduate school applications.

> If the student takes more than 8 semesters to graduate, is it a problem?

No.  **Nobody cares.**  Even if someone on a grad admission committee *noticed*, the longer time would quickly be explained by your coop semesters and your change in majors.

> Should the student (if they can) extend their studies by an additional semester so that they graduate in the spring, or is a fall graduation equally acceptable.

Acceptable to whom?  If you mean graduate admissions committees, then I repeat: **Nobody cares.**  In particular, graduating in the spring is no barrier to starting a graduate program the following fall.  (Of course, you have to eat, but that's a separate issue.)

> Do grad programs accept students to start in the spring, or only the fall?

Some do, some don't.  **Every grad program is different.**

One last point: You mention coops, GPAs, and program reputation, but those are not the most significant bits.  Graduate admissions committees at top departments are primarily looking for **strong evidence of research potential**.  Assuming my quick Google search correctly identifies your university, you should have *lots* of opportunities for undergraduate research experience with world-class faculty.  Take advantage of them!  **Start now!**

Comment: Thank you JeffE. Your answer takes care of my major concerns, I am planning on starting a serious research position once I return.

Comment: -1 for "nobody cares." Admissions committees might not care, but the undergraduate institution might, particularly with respect to financial aid. Check with your school _before_ deciding to extend your study time beyond eight semesters! (My undergraduate institution, for instance, **refused** to allow students extra semesters, whether it was for coops, internships, study abroad, or almost any other reason beyond serious medical or financial problems.)